# Use existing publication list for a triggered send

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send, subscriber, send-email, publicationlist

Till now marketing team at my company had been sending out the newsletters manually using the publication list. There are over 100,000 subscribers in that list. Now we have created a triggered send for a different category of newsletter and want to use the same publication list so that any unsubscribes/subscribes from that publication list are taken into account for triggered send. But when creating a triggered send I do not have access to publication list. I have 2 questions:

- How can I use data from the publication list during triggered send
- Also I want that it should be 1 list for both manual and triggered newsletters. There are still some category of newsletters that need to be triggered manually.

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need to configure it in the UI:

When you configure your Triggered Send, in **Subscriber Management** secrion, there are two separate sections called List and “Triggered Send” Data Extensions.

The purpose of the first one, List, is subscriber management. Either choose All Subscribers or a dedicated publication list if you have one. Failing to select a list results in use of the Triggered Send Managed List, a hidden system-defined List, to track status. Avoid this scenario as the Triggered Send Managed List does not support all triggered send-based functionality.

You will also notice two checkboxes under the List section:

Add subscribers to this list determines whether the list accepts new subscriber information of subscribers who trigger this email interaction. If selected, the send adds the subscriber to a selected list if that email address does not already appear on the list. If, for example, you’re using the All Subscribers list to manage subscriber statuses, and the subscriber who triggers this email interaction is not yet there, they will be added there.

Update Subscribers determines whether an existing subscriber’s attributes should be updated if you pass in new data for that subscriber via the API call.

Here’s a screenshot of the section where you can choose your List:

[image]

See here for more on Triggered Sends: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/11/25/introduction-to-triggered-sends/